# What do the letter-number codes under my name mean?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

I would take a screenshot and use free-hand circles, but alas, I don't have a way to do so with my Xbox.

Under my name, in my player card, there is the string "E5". I have seen others on other players, such as "E4", "C3", etc. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letter-number code on your player card is your multiplayer rank in Ranked matches (not Player matches or Global Colosseo matches). Every time you play a match on XBox Live or PSN, you gain experience towards your next rank (this is separate from the leveling procedure for offline games, which unlocks you additional creation gear). The amount of experience will vary. It is dependent on your opponent's rank and whether or not you win or lose (and probably some other unidentified factors).

The ranks go from E (worst) to A (best), and 5 (worst) down to 1 (best), with a transition to the next highest letter when you get to the lowest number (e.g. E1 levels up to D5). You start at E5, and there are achievements/trophies for achieving higher ranks.

This is also a good way to estimate the difficulty level of opponents in Quick Battle offline; an estimation of appropriate rank is given for each of these opponents.

Comment: So far, I have only played in the Global Colosseo mode online, and have not noticed any changing in rank. Is this limited to only ranked matches?

Comment: @StrixVaria yep - gotta be Ranked only. Edited.